# how should i put data fetched from ajax call in hidden div box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am working on a project and come across a module.

**page1**
user have to search from search bar which will take him to page 2.

**page2**
On page 2 all fetched results will get displayed to user in div's. Each result has a checkbox associated with it.
[image: result format]

when i click on add to compare  check box ,ajax call is executed and fetched selected result should appear in hidden div.

my problem is it is only shows first result in hidden div and not working with another result.[image]

My code of page 2

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var check = $('#compare').val();
    $("#compare").change(function() {
if(this.checked) {        
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'compare.php',
        dataType : 'JSON',
        data:{value : check},
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
            $('#compare_box').html(data);               
        }
    });       

  $("#compare_box").show();
}
else
{
    $("#compare_box").hide();
}       
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$query = $_GET['search_bar'];
$query = "call fetch_data('$query')"or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $id = $row['course_id'];
$title = $row['course_title'];
$description = $row['course_description'];
$course_url = $row['course_url'];
$video_url = $row['course_video_url'];
$fee = $row['course_fee'];
$duration = $row['course_duration'];
$start_date = $row['course_start_date'];
$university = $row['university_name'];
$course_provider = $row['course_provider_name'];
$instructor = $row['instructor_name'];

         $_SESSION['result'][$id]  = Array('id'=> $id,'course_title' => $title,'course_description'=> $description,'course_url' => $course_url,'video_url' => $video_url,'fee' => $fee,'course_duration'=>$duration,'start_date'=>$start_date,'university' => $university,'course_provider'=>$course_provider,'instructor'=>$instructor);
?>
    <div id='compare_box'>                  
        </div>      

     <div class="col-md-3 photo-grid " style="float:left">

        <div class="well well-sm">

       <a href="final.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>&name=<?php echo $title;?>" target="_blank">
        <h4><small><?php echo $title; ?></small></h4>
       </a>
     <br>
     <input type ='checkbox' name="compare" id="compare" value="<?php echo $id;?>">add to compare
     </div>
</div>
<?php  
}
?>
```

**page3 compare.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'includes/dbconfig.php';
$check = $_POST['value'];
$sql = "SELECT * from course_info_table where course_id = '$check' " or   die(mysqli_error($conn));
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$index = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $title = $row['course_title'];

 ?>
<?php
}
echo json_encode($title);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change

```
<input type ='checkbox' name="compare" id="compare" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
```

to

`<input type ='checkbox' name="compare" class="compare" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
                                           ^you can only have one unique 'id' value in your html doc, which means your first id="compare" will work fine and others with id="compare" will be ignored by the DOM tree`

Reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

Comment: oh thanks,that worked fine,now when i 'm clicking add to compare checkbox its just passing first result value ,